# Only two media query breakpoints in my css work..why doesn't the rest also work?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, breakpoints

My question is why will only the iphones min and max widths load in my css but
not my ipads min and max widths? I know that all my css does work individually but not all together. I also tried using multiple stylesheets instead but i had the same issue..where only the last 2 stylesheets would load.

```
<head>
<title></title>

<meta charset="UTF-8"/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css?v=1"/>

</head>




container, header, menu, home-info {
display: inline-block;
}


body {
background-color: pearl white;
}


#container {
width: 50%;
height: 800px;
background-color: white;

position: fixed;
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
box-shadow:  0 0 75px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 0.8);
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
color: white;
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-size: 220px;
background-color: grey;

}



.menu {
position: absolute;
top: 205px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
padding: 5px;

}

.menu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float:left;

}

.menu ul li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
position:relative;
}
.menu ul li a{

display:block;

    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 775px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}
.menu ul li a:hover{

    background: yellow;
    color: #00357d;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px 5px yellow;
}

.menu ul ul{

    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul{

visibility:visible;
}




.menu ul ul li a:hover {

background: yellow;
color: #00357d;

}
.menu ul ul ul  {

visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;

}
.menu ul ul li:hover ul {

visibility: visible;
}



.menu ul ul ul li a:hover {

background: yellow;
color: #00357d;

}
.menu ul ul ul ul  {

visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;

}
.menu ul ul ul li:hover ul {

visibility: visible;
}

.menu ul ul ul ul li a:hover {

background: yellow;
color: #00357d;

}
.menu ul ul ul ul ul  {

    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;

}
.menu ul ul ul ul li:hover ul {

    visibility: visible;
}

.home-info {
color: grey;
font-size: 20px;
top: 550px;

position: absolute;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

/*max-ipads*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){

    #container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: white;

    position: fixed;

    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    box-shadow:  0 0 75px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
.header {

position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 105px;
    background-color: grey;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
.menu {

position: absolute;

    top: 75px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 5px;

}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
.menu ul li a{

display:block;

    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 350px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
.home-info {
color: grey;
font-size: 15px;
top: 420px;

position: absolute;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
}

/*---min-width---*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
#container {
width: 50%;
height: 1024px;
background-color: white;

position: fixed;

transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
box-shadow:  0 0 75px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 0.8);
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
.header {

height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: grey;
color: white;
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;

position: absolute;

text-align: center;
font-size: 80px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
.menu {

position: absolute;

top: 55px;
left: 50%;
padding: 5px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
.menu ul li a{

display:block;

    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 480px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
.home-info {

color: grey;
font-size: 21px;
top: 430px;

position: absolute;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
}

/*iphones-max*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
#container {

width: 50%;
height: 350px;
background-color: white;

position: fixed;

transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
box-shadow:  0 0 75px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 0.8);
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.header {

height: 50px;
width: 100%;
color: white;
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;

position: absolute;

text-align: center;
font-size: 50px;
background-color: grey;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.menu {

position: absolute;

top: 55px;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
padding: 5px;

}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.menu ul li a{

display:block;

    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 125px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.home-info {

color: grey;
font-size: 10px;
top: 270px;

position: absolute;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
}

/*smartphone-min*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
#container {

width: 50%;
height: 420px;
background-color: white;

position: fixed;

transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
box-shadow:  0 0 75px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 0.8);
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
.header {

height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: grey;
color: white;
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;

position: absolute;

text-align: center;
font-size: 80px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
.menu {

position: absolute;

left: 50%;
padding: 5px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
margin-top: 30px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
.menu ul li a{

display:block;

    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: silver;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
.home-info {

color: grey;
font-size: 10px;
top: 320px;

position: absolute;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly how your styles are laid in your stylesheet (tough to tell without seeing an actual source), then I believe your problem is NOT that the iPad styles aren't loading - it's that they are loading in the wrong order.

You should **lay out your styles from smallest (top) to largest (bottom)** (i.e. 320 then 480 then 768 etc.). Otherwise your smaller screen styles are likely overriding your larger screen styles.

For example, if I do:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .box { background: red; }
}

@media (min-width: 420px) {
    .box { background: yellow; }
}
```

The `background` color will be yellow on any screen from 420px to 1024px.

Therefore, you need to either switch the order from smaller to larger OR you can get more specific with your media queries. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .box { background: red }
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying is have both min and max width together..then style the page so it looks good inbetween 768-1024.. i think you answered my question thanks!

Comment: There are certainly different conventions you can follow (especially if you are using a preprocessor like Less or Sass), but generally speaking you should define the styles for the smallest screens at the top of your stylesheet. Also if this helped, can you mark my answer as solved? Thanks